# JavaScript multiline strings and templating?

Tags: javascript, html, templates

I have been wondering if there is a way to define multiline strings in JavaScript like you can do in languages like PHP:

```
var str = "here
goes
another
line";
```

Apparently this breaks up the parser. I found that placing a backslash \ in front of the line feed solves the problem:

```
var str = "here\
goes\
another\
line";
```

Or I could just close and reopen the string quotes again and again.

The reason why I am asking because I am making JavaScript based UI widgets that utilize HTML templates written in JavaScript. It is painful to type HTML in strings especially if you need to open and close quotes all the time. What would be a good way to define HTML templates within JavaScript?

I am considering using separate HTML files and a compilation system to make everything easier, but the library is distributed among other developers so that HTML templates have to be easy to include for the developers.

Answer (score 1):

No thats basically what you have to do to do multiline strings.

But why define the templates in javascript anwyay? why not just put them into a file and have a ajax call load them up in a variable when you need them?

For instantce (using jquery)

```
$.get('/path/to/template.html', function(data) {
  alert(data); //will alert the template code
});
```

Comment: Because it takes time to do an XHR per each template? Or do you have ways to circumvent that or other suggestions?

Comment: Unless the templates are huge, and the server extremely slowed, the time should be negligible (500ms to 2 seconds should be the norm) and you only do it when you need the template, not all at once. After you have retrieved the template just store it in a javascript variable so you can use it when you need it.

Comment: @rFactor: See my answer for how I circumvented this issue.

Comment: @slebetman: you circumvented the issue of the time it takes in using ajax?

Comment: @Patrick: Yes, I circumvented the `per each template` bit. For me it was using a small set of templates hundreds of times which led to only around half a dozen ajax requests for hundreds of template uses. If you instead have hundreds of templates that you use once each then you can aggregate them into a larger XML file and extract individual templates from that one ajax request.

Comment: @Patrick: The key is to set aggressive caching policy for the templates on the server side. Then you don't need to write your own caching code - just let the browser handle it.

Answer (score 1):

@slebetman, Thanks for the detailed example.
Quick comment on the substitute_strings function.
I had to revise

```
 str.replace(n,substitutions[n]);
```

to be

```
 str = str.replace(n,substitutions[n]);
```

to get it to work. (jQuery version 1.5? - it is pure javascript though.)

Also when I had below situation in my template:

```
$CONTENT$ repeated twice $CONTENT$ like this
```

I had to do additional processing to get it to work.

```
 str = str.replace(new RegExp(n, 'g'), substitutions[n]);
```

And I had to refrain from `$` (regex special char) as the delimiter and used `#` instead.
Thought I would share my findings.

Answer (score 0):

There are several templating systems in javascript. However, my personal favorite is one I developed myself using ajax to fetch XML templates. The templates are XML files which makes it easy to embed HTML cleanly and it looks something like this:

```
<title>This is optional</title>
<body><![CDATA[
    HTML content goes here, the CDATA block prevents XML errors
    when using non-xhtml html.

    <div id="more">
      $CONTENT$ may be substituted using replace() before being
      inserted into $DOCUMENT$.
    </div>
]]></body>
<script><![CDATA[
    /* javascript code to be evaled after template
     * is inserted into document. This is to get around
     * the fact that this templating system does not
     * have its own turing complete programming language.
     * Here's an example use:
     */
     if ($HIDE_MORE$) {
       document.getElementById('more').display = 'none';
     }
]]></script>
```

And the javascript code to process the template goes something like this:

```
function insertTemplate (url_to_template, insertion_point, substitutions) {
  // Ajax call depends on the library you're using, this is my own style:
  ajax(url_to_template, function (request) {
    var xml = request.responseXML;
    var title = xml.getElementsByTagName('title');
    if (title) {
      insertion_point.innerHTML += substitute_strings(title[0],substitutions);
    }
    var body = xml.getElementsByTagName('body');
    if (body) {
      insertion_point.innerHTML += substitute_strings(body[0],substitutions);
    }
    var script = xml.getElementsByTagName('script');
    if (script) {
      eval(substitute_strings(script[0],substitutions));
    }
  });
}

function substitute_strings (str, substitutions) {
  for (var n in substitutions) {
    str.replace(n,substitutions[n]);
  }
  return str;
}
```

The way to call the template would be:

```
insertTemplate('http://path.to.my.template', myDiv, {
  '$CONTENT$' : "The template's content",
  '$DOCUMENT$' : "the document",
  '$HIDE_MORE$' : 0
});
```

The `$` sign for substituted strings is merely a convention, you may use `%` of `#` or whatever delimiters you prefer. It's just there to make the part to be substituted unambiguous.

One big advantage to using substitutions on the javascript side instead of server side processing of the template is that this allows the template to be plain static files. The advantage of that (other than not having to write server side code) is that you can then set the caching policy for the template to be very aggressive so that the browser only needs to fetch the template the first time you load it. Subsequent use of the template would come from cache and would be very fast.

Also, this is a very simple example of the implementation to illustrate the mechanism. It's not what I'm using. You can modify this further to do things like multiple substitution, better handling of script block, handle multiple content blocks by using a for loop instead of just using the first element returned, properly handling HTML entities etc.

The reason I really like this is that the HTML is simply HTML in a plain text file. This avoids quoting hell and horrible string concatenation performance issues that you'll usually find if you directly embed HTML strings in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution I like.

I will store templates in files and fetch them using AJAX. This works for development stage only. For production stage, the developer has to run a compiler once that compiles all templates with the source files. It also compiles JavaScript and CSS to be more compact and it compiles them to a single file.

The biggest problem now is how to educate other developers doing that. I need to build it so that it is easy to do and understand why and what are they doing.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use \n to generate newlines. The html would however be on a single line and difficult to edit. But if you generate the JS using PHP or something it might be an alternative